# Include variable scope issue

Tags: php, variables, scope

I'm having issues with something very simple but I've search for hours and have no idea what is going,

to break the problem down to the simplest form here is an example

page-a.php

```
$test = 'hello';
include('page-b.php');
```

page-b.php

```
echo $test;
```

The above is stating undefined variable test for me..., i'm beginning to wonder if it is a setting in the ini? any ideas?

Comment: page-b.php: `global $test; echo $test;`

Comment: what you want to as  a output ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the variable as `global`

*page-a.php*

```
global $test;
$test = 'hello';
include('page-b.php');
```

Comment: I've tested every which way, using $GLOBALS etc, the above does not work either.

Comment: @user1372212..It is working for me. I have tried it in my localhost.

Comment: is there an ini setting that relates to this at all?

Answer (score 0):

Note: Here you are declaring the $test variable into the page-a.php and you use it in page-b.php, then How is it possible?
Because

1. You can use $test only in page-a.php
2. You can use all the page-b.php variables inside the page-a.php file.